# Django ModelForm: change a field value when blank

Tags: django, django-forms

Is there any way to change a field value (related to a foreign key) in a Django `ModelForm` once the form is initialized and filled by the user (I'm using `request.POST`). I want to change the value when the user doesn't select any option of the dropdown list. I tried this `formulari_mostra.data['pools'] = 1` in `views.py` after saving the feedback from the form with no result:

```
def sample_form(request):

    formulari_mostra=FormulariMostra() 

    if request.method=="POST":

        formulari_mostra=FormulariMostra(request.POST or None)

        if formulari_mostra.is_valid():

            feedback = formulari_mostra.save(commit=False)
            sample = Sample.objects.all()
            feedback.sample = sample
            feedback.save()
            formulari_mostra.save_m2m()
            formulari_mostra.data['pools'] = 1
            messages.success(request, 'Mostra enregistrada correctament!')        

     return render(request, "sample/formulari_mostra.html", {'formulari':formulari_mostra})
```

I got this message:

```
This QueryDict instance is immutable
```

I know I can set an initial (default) before introducing data in the form but I don't want to have the default option highlighted in the dropdown.

My model:

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    id_sample = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20)
    sample_id_sex = models.ForeignKey(Sex, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='id_sex', verbose_name='Sexe')
    indexes = models.ManyToManyField(Index, through='SamplePoolIndexCand', through_fields=('sample_id', 'index_id'), blank=True, verbose_name="Índexs")
    pools = models.ManyToManyField(Pool, through='SamplePoolIndexCand', through_fields=('sample_id', 'pool_id'), blank=True, verbose_name="Pools")
    gene_cand_lists = models.ManyToManyField(GeneCandList, through='SamplePoolIndexCand', through_fields=('sample_id', 'gene_cand_list_id'), blank=True, verbose_name="Llista de gens candidats")

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'sample'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My `forms.py`:

```
class FormulariMostra(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
        model = Sample
        fields = ("name", "sample_id_sex", "pools",)
```

Comment: At what point are you trying to change the data - in your view or in the form or elsewhere? Add more context please

Comment: You have to use initial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#initial-form-values

Comment: More context added.

Answer (score 0):

first - you are setting the `polls` property after `save()` is called, so even if this would work, you are not saving the change.

second - if you want to set the `polls` property to model, then set it to the model instead of the form (`formulari_mostra`). I dont know how your models look like, so I can only assume the model which has the `pools` property is in the variable `feedback`, so you want to do:

```
feedback = formulari_mostra.save(commit=False)
feedback.pools = 1
feedback.save()
```

Comment: Added my model and `forms.py`. Using `feedback.pools = 1` I got this error `TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use pools.set() instead.` and with `feedback.pools.set(1)` this: `"<Sample: X>" needs to have a value for field "id_sample" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`